# Generate a grid from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, grid

I have this array of blocks:

```
let blocks = [Blocks]()
```

I add 16 blocks into that array. And here is how I generate a 4x4 grid:

```
for i in 0...3 {
            for j in 0...3 {
                for b in blocks {
                    b.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i)*b.frame.size.width + xOffset, y: yPos)
                    addChild(b)  <<-- Error here
                    yPos = yPos - b.frame.size.height - yOffset

                }
            }
```

I get this error:

```
Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you replace the line

```
for b in blocks
```

with

```
let b = blocks[i*4 + j]
```

You are adding all of the blocks 16 times with the current code